# Querystring search on array elements in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to learn elasticsearch with a simple example application, that lists quotations associated with people. The example mapping might look like:

```
{ 
  "people" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : { "type" : "string"},
      "quotations" : { "type" : "string" }
    }
  }
}
```

Some example data might look like:

```
{ "name" : "Mr A",
  "quotations" : [ "quotation one, this and that and these"
                 , "quotation two, those and that"]
}

{ "name" : "Mr B",
  "quotations" : [ "quotation three, this and that"
                 , "quotation four, those and these"]
}
```

I would like to be able to use the querystring api on individual quotations, and return the people who match. For instance, I might want to find people who have a quotation that contains (this AND these) - which should return "Mr A" but not "Mr B", and so on. How can I achieve this?

EDIT1:

Andrei's answer below seems to work, with data values now looking like:

```
{"name":"Mr A","quotations":[{"value" : "quotation one, this and that and these"}, {"value" : "quotation two, those and that"}]}
```

However, I can't seem to get a query_string query to work. The following produces no results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "quotations",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "quotations",
            "query": "quotations.value:this AND these"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get a query_string query working with a nested object?

Edit2: Yes it is, see Andrei's answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For that requirement to be achieved, you need to look at nested objects, not to query a flattened list of values but individual values from that nested object. For example:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "people": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "quotations": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Values:

```
{"name":"Mr A","quotations":[{"value": "quotation one, this and that and these"}, {"value": "quotation two, those and that"}]}
{"name":"Mr B","quotations":[{"value": "quotation three, this and that"}, {"value": "quotation four, those and these"}]}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "quotations",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": {"quotations.value": "this"}},
            { "match": {"quotations.value": "these"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to change the Values to look like: `{"name":"Mr A","quotations":[{"value" : "quotation one, this and that and these"}, {"value" : "quotation two, those and that"}]}`, but this worked. Is there any way to use a QueryStringQuery with this? I tried using one (just replacing the bool with query_string), and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: You're right. Now I noticed that I copy-pasted the wrong values, even though I tested with the correct ones (the ones you mentioned).

Comment: Try this: `{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "quotations",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "quotations.value",
          "query": "this AND these"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Ah, I just had default_field as quotations. This works, many thanks!

Comment: As an update for ElasticSearch 6.2 (at least), an error occurs when you try to use the `string` type in a mappint. The error from running this is `No handler for type [string] declared on field [value]`. Similar valid types are now `text` and `keyword` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html).

Comment: @Tayler yes, agree. Many things have changed since I posted that solution :-). `string` doesn't exist anymore, you should be ok to use either `text` or `keyword` - they are slightly irrelevant for the solution. The type of the field becomes relevant if you do care how `match` matches the values, but for the core solution of this post the type of the field, as I said, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no good way to do that.
https://web.archive.org/web/20141021073225/http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html

> When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in
> the same order as when you indexed the document. The _source field
> that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you
> indexed.
>
> However, arrays are indexed — made searchable — as multi-value fields,
> which are unordered. At search time you can’t refer to “the first
> element” or “the last element”. Rather think of an array as a bag of
> values.

In other words, it is always considering all values in the array.

This will return only Mr A

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "quotations": {
        "query": "quotation one",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this will return both Mr A & Mr B:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "quotations": {
        "query": "this these",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html) is enabled, this should work:

```
"script": {
   "inline": "for(element in _source.quotations) { if(element == 'this' && element == 'these') {return true;} }; return false;"
 }
```