# Elasticsearch Search in nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, nosql

Hi i'm elasticsearch newbie and i have troubles with a query. I have data's as

```
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "date": "141462121",
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe"
    "activity": [
      {
        "type": [
          "Outdoor",
          "Extreme"
        ],
        "name": "Example",
        "price": {
          "value": 50,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
    "searchs": ""
  }
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "date": "141462121",
    "name": "Jane",
    "surname": "Doe"
    "activity": [
      {
        "type": [
          "Indoor"
        ],
        "name": "Example2",
        "price": {
          "value": 100,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": [
          "Outdoor"
        ],
        "name": "Example3",
        "price": {
          "value": 25,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
    "searchs": ""
  }
}
```

and i want to search these datas by activity type. i tried [nested queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258292/querystring-search-on-array-elements-in-elastic-search) like

```
"query": {
  "nested": {
     "path": "activity",
     "query": {
         "bool": {
             "must": [
                {"match": {
                   "activity.type": "outdoor"
                }}
           ]
       }
   }
}
```

and like

```
"query": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "activity",
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "type",
        "query": {
           "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {"match": {
                     "type.value": "outdoor"
                  }}
               ]
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but i couldn't succeed.

How can i search these datas by activity type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple match query if you're just looking for records with an activity type like

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "activity.type": "Outdoor"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When i use this. i can get only first acitivity's type records which has multiple activity for example when i run this query i can't get "Jane Doe" record.

Comment: Are you sure there are 2 records on your index? And that when you are querying, you're not specifying a page size of 1? You can try using a plugin like head to browse your index.

Comment: yes i'm sure i have larg amount of data but i sampled 15 example for trying. when i run query it doesn't gets users with multiple activities.

Comment: Can you display the output you get when running the query above?

Comment: Oh i found the error. it doesn't found because of charset error on my console. Thank you.