# filtering in kibana to get certain data from array

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Data in my kibana is like this

```
{"code": "A",
 "sentences": [
    {
     "match_num": 1,
     "sentence": "I like apples",
     "date": "20180109"
     },
    {
     "match_num": 0,
     "sentence": "I like kiwi",
     "date": "20180109"
     },
    {
     "match_num": 0,
     "sentence": "I like banana",
     "date": "20180109"
     },
    {
     "match_num": 2,
     "sentence": "I like carrots",
     "date": "20180109"
     }
  ]
}
```

what I want to do is just extract sentences where match_num is not zero. I tried sentences.match_num:[1 TO *] but this gives all of sentences. What I want to see is like below

```
{"code": "A",
 "sentences": [
    {
     "match_num": 1,
     "sentence": "I like apples",
     "date": "20180109"
     },
    {
     "match_num": 2,
     "sentence": "I like carrots",
     "date": "20180109"
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When you do a query you are asking for every document that contains the thing you are querying. Your document in this case is the outer object that contains the array so as your query matches you get the whole document back.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258292/querystring-search-on-array-elements-in-elastic-search

Comment: Thanks to both Duncan and MrSimple. I didn't use `nested`, so I decide to change the structure of data