# Elastic: Nested Query or Query of elastic Documents by document key whose values are arrays of key, value pair

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I am trying to form a query in elastic, the documents are stored like this-

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum",
            "source": [
                "abc.com", "xyz.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": "Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum",
            "source": [
                "wxy.com", "osa.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter the documents by a certain source.

I've got some idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258292/querystring-search-on-array-elements-in-elastic-search) but it's not working. It's returning all the records in all the queries for this field.

I've exhausted all permutations and combinations of queries in my knowledge so far. So, any idea how can I achieve this?

**Mapping:-**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_document_name_": {
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "properties": {
                        "source": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Query:-**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "address",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                        { "match": {"data.source": "abc.com"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your index mapping and also the queries you've tried?

Comment: @Val question updated.

Comment: You're using a nested query, yet your `data` field is not nested. That's an issue

Comment: @Val I understand, it's an issue for this particular case. Can it be achieved by other means?

Comment: No, you need the `data` field to be nested if you want to achieve what you want.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll change the mapping and try it again. @Val